# Reusing extracted log values for efficient queries

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I'm moderately new to the world of metrics visualization and have been working in Grafana. One thing I have to do often is a 0.5/0.95/0.99 quantile chart of a set of data. The data, for legacy reasons (for now), is extracted from logs via LogQL with Loki.

This is working as-expected, but is slow and outright fails for extended (over 2 weeks?) time periods.

```
quantile_over_time(0.5, {app="my-awesome-app"} |= "build_time_seconds" |= "MacBook" | pattern "<_>} <metric_value>\\<_>" | unwrap metric_value [1d])
```

The above is then repeated twice more for the 0.95 and 0.99 quantiles.

This looks to me like the data extraction portion is doing redundant work; the same set of data is extracted for each quantile query. If I could extract first, then perform quantiles on that cached extraction, I think that would be a much more performant way of doing things.

Can this be done? Using a dashboard as a data source *feels* like the right path, but I do not see an obvious way forward with that method. I also don't see any way to insert a reference to a query result such as `quantile_over_time(0.5, <data_I_extracted_in_a_previous_query>)`

Comment: have you tried looking at recording rules? https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/rules/

Comment: @DanDinu I've been looking at that, yes. However it appears to apply this pre-processing at the time data arrives at Grafana servers. It doesn't seem to be available as a post-process on a trove of existing data, if I understand it correctly.